# Why does my script timeout? - BeautifulSoup Timeout Error

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, timeout

I am trying to scrape a significant amount of data and loop through many pages. I keep receiving a timeout error when i exceed 5 or so pages in the loop.

```
### Libraries ###

import pyppdf.patch_pyppeteer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import urllib.request

### SCRAPING PAGES 1-15

all_beer_info = []
for i in range(1,16):
    url = 'https://specsonline.com/product-category/beer/page/{}/'.format(i)
    print(url)
    session = HTMLSession()  
    resp = session.get(url, timeout=None)
    site = resp.html.render() #RENDERS INCASE ITS JAVASCRIPT SITE
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.html.html, features='lxml')
    beer_info = soup.select('.woocommerce-loop-product__title')
    for b in beer_info:
        results = (b.text)
        all_beer_info.append(results)
    sleep(randint(2,5))
```

Sometimes this will run through the entire script without error, others times it returns the following:
`pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 8000 ms exceeded.`

I have four different loops like the one above to scrape: Name, Price, Product Size, etc.

If it makes it through one or two loops it will timeout before the code completes, rendering that time useless. Is there a more efficient way to run this code and combine the data? Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that for "full render" with all js stuff some pages needs more then 8 seconds and you receive `TimeoutError`. 8 seconds is default timeout for `resp.html.render()`.
Try something like `resp.html.render(timeout=20)`

Comment: Great, that worked! I didnt realize i could pass the timeout parameter through the render.